# Unable to Deploy WP7 SDK Application on Windows Phone 8 Through VS2012

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have Registered my device for developer. 
But after choosing device in VS2012 and start deploying , It Gives  error .
**Unable to install application. The maximum number of developer applications on this phone has been reached. Please uninstall a developer application and try again.**

I am new to deployment on device . Please suggest .

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to have multiple Windows Phone 8 devices? It turns out that if you register two devices under the same name, this problem arises. I had registered two Windows Phone Devices for development, but I hadn't given them a unique name (they were both named the default, which is Windows Phone, I think). On the first device, I had multiple test apps installed and, obviously, on the second device, nothing was installed, hence my frustration regarding the error. I did the following to make it work:

- Remove the phone(s) from the [dev portal](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/Account/Devices),
- Unregister both devices using Windows Phone Developer Registration.
- [Rename the devices](http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8/202470-rename-device.html), making sure their names are not the same.
- Re-register the phones again, now with new, unique names.

I hope it works for you as well.

Comment: Thanks Muncken ,But I tried This also But didn't worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall the unwanted applications from the device.
2. Restart the device
3. Try to deploy the solution. It will work now.

Comment: Thanks  David , But  I tried it a lot times . But still i am stuck here .

Answer (score 0):

It means you have installed three(3) testing app. windows phone have limit of max 3 app installation for debug.

1. Uninstall one of your previously installed application.
2. Now deploy your new application again.

Hope will work now.

Comment: hi freakToWm  , I have no applications Installed , My Phone Is Nokia Lumia 520 , and it's a brand new Phone . I Unlocked It for developer ,  and now this is the problem .

Comment: you can try with factory reset the phone & unlocking the phone for developer again. Hope this time you should get rid of this issue. Thanks.